# C++ SQLite3 query issue unsolved

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I'm somewhat new to SQL and C++. I do believe the question I have yields a simple solution.

I have to create a sql query to insert some values into an existing table (const char *sql_query), with mixed strings and float values. My issue is getting the string assembly operation nailed down, without getting compiler errors.

Here is my attempt:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    create_entry("mahut", "topa", "suma", 5.55, 6.66, 7.77);

    return 0;
}

void create_entry(char col1[], char col2[], char col3[], float col4, float col5, float col6)
{
    cout << ("create_entry") << endl;

    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;
    char *sql;
    char db_name[] = "db_test.db";
    stringstream sql_query;

    // assemble string
    sql_query << "INSERT INTO Department1 (Date,Time,Accept,Factor1,Factor2,Factor3) VALUES ('" << col1 << "','" << col2 << "','" << col3 << "','" << col4 << "','" << col5 << "','" << col6 << "')";
    string str = sql_query.str();

    rc = sqlite3_open(db_name, &db);

    if( rc )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
    }

    // execute SQL statement
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, str, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);

    if( rc != SQLITE_OK )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Records created successfully\n");
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
}

static int callback(void *db, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    cout << "Debug <in callback>" << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<argc; ++i)
    {
        //printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
        cout << ("%s", argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL") << endl;
    }
    tbl_exists = true;

    return 0;
}
```

Particularly this is my problem:

```
sql_query << "INSERT INTO Department1 (Date,Time,Accept,Factor1,Factor2,Factor3) VALUES ('" << col1 << "','" << col2 << "','" << col3 << "','" << col4 << "','" << col5 << "','" << col6 << "')";
```

As I don't understand if there is a proper way to mix in float, integer and string into const char *
I'm not sure what's wrong, but like I said I have tried it for quite some time to properly assemble that string but have failed, as I just don't grasp pointers and strings in C++. Compiling fails due to following error

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int sqlite3_exec(sqlite3*, const char*, int (*)(void*, int, char**, char**), void*, char**)’   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, str, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
```

I also get the following warning

```
warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
```

Comment: Get rid of the `char[]` and use `std::string` instead and watch your problems melt away

Comment: Are you referring to the function parameters? like so void create_entry(std::string col1, std::string col2, std::string col3, float col4, float col5, float col6)??

Comment: Yes, those are the uses of `char[]` I'm referring to

Comment: Still getting that error
error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int sqlite3_exec(sqlite3*, const char*, int (*)(void*, int, char**, char**), void*, char**)’   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, str, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);

Answer (score 0):

For your error, you're missing a `.c_str()` conversion of the std::string to a C-style string.   sqlite3_exec takes C-style `const char *` strings, not C++ strings.

For your warning, you'll need to declare your parameters to `create_entry()` as `const char *` (or `const char []`) - because they're literals (constants that should not be modified).  Declaring them non-const opens you up to accidentally modifying them.

Comment: Yeah that I understand, my question is how do I noodle all my values into  (const char *sql_query)? These are the values I want in there: ("mahut", "topa", "suma", 5.55, 6.66, 7.77)) into the following line: "INSERT INTO Department1 (Date,Time,Accept,Factor1,Factor2,Factor3) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %f, %f, %f)", col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6);
//----------------------------
How do I do that?

Comment: You're on the right track with std::stringstream.  What do you get if you do cout << str << std::endl; ?  Seems like you've got the right pieces there, creating a string stream then extracting the string from it to pass to the query.

Comment: That outputs: INSERT INTO Department1 (Date,Time,Accept,Factor1,Factor2,Factor3) VALUES ('mahut','topa','suma','5.55','6.66','7.77')                               But I still get that error when compiling and trying to execute the query: error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int sqlite3_exec(sqlite3*, const char*, int (*)(void*, int, char**, char**), void*, char**)’
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, str, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);

Comment: See answer above: you're missing .c_str() after str to convert std::string to a c-style "const char *" string.

Comment: I have this line in there: string str = sql_query.str(); and then I execute the query with that: rc = sqlite3_exec(db, str, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);

Comment: You want `sqlite3_exec(db, str.c_str(), callback, 0, &zErrMsg);`

Comment: :-) Works, I also did the following: before ani #include I added  #define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 0, then I also updated gcc and g++ to version 6. something like so: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gcc-6
sudo apt install g++-6
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-6 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-6

Answer (score 0):

Assembling the string becomes easier if you are not doing it at all:

```
void create_entry(const char col1[], const char col2[], const char col3[],
                  float col4, float col5, float col6)
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    int rc;
    const char *sql;
    static const char db_name[] = "db_test.db";
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    sql = "INSERT INTO Department1 (Date,Time,Accept,Factor1,Factor2,Factor3)"
          " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    rc = sqlite3_open(db_name, &db);
    if( rc != SQLITE_OK )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return;
    }

    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
    if( rc != SQLITE_OK )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't prepare query: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return;
    }

    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, col1, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, col2, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, col3, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 4, col4);
    sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 5, col5);
    sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 6, col6);

    rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    if( rc != SQLITE_DONE )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't execute query: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return;
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);
}
```